# Displaying HTML Divs over Silverlight

Tags: html, css, silverlight

Is it possible to have HTML appearing above embedded Silverlight?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes but you need to set the windowless param to true on the Silverlight object tag so that it can render behind other HTML objects.

Comment: Nice....that helped me a lot! :D. For more information on the silverlight object in html, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838259(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Anthony is right - I've shown a code snippet [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/synergist/archive/2008/09/16/added-high-dpi-support-to-my-silverlight-photobucket-demonstration-application.aspx) on my blog.  You need to implement the  in your object element and then use CSS Z-index.

Answer (score 2):

More info about layering HTML elements on top of or underneath your Silverlight control here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/02/15/using-windowless-silverlight-controls-to-blend-html-and-silverlight-elements.aspx

Note that there are [performance impacts in using windowless and/or transparent controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189071(VS.95).aspx#windowless_true_is_expensive) since it requires more frequent redrawing, so it's not recommended for animation or video playback.